# Sanitize content when batch creating WooCommerce products via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I'm creating products in my WooCommerce store via the WooCommerce REST API, using the `products/batch` endpoint.

I've noticed that within a batch, if WooCommerce has an issue with any of the data sent across in the batch, the array returned is empty. Instead of it returning the array of all items except the one which it has an issue with.

When I used this description in one of the products it did not like it and the WooCommerce REST API response was then just `[]`.

**Content which WooCommerce did not like:**

```
This is an example. ¥ 50% Polyester/25% Cotton/25% Rayon* ¥ Racerback ¥ Form-fitting * Tri-oatmeal is made of 50% polyester/37% cotton/13% rayon
```

You can see symbols like: `¥` which is likely the cause.

I am dealing with user generated content so I can't always know what weird symbols may appear in the batches of products I try to create.

**My Setup:**.
**Server #1**:
This server is what handles grabbing all data from the CSV's which users upload, it has had no problems grabbing the data, however maybe it's better to sanitise it immediately before sending to WooCommerce?

**Server #2**:
This server is where WordPress/WooCommerce is installed, WooCommerce recieves the data and does all its usual wp_insert_post etc.

Comment: It's probably a server-specific issue because I tried creating products having that exact description and WooCommerce actually returned a valid array (when doing batch) or object (when creating a single product). But as with escaping (the special characters) prior to creating the product, you could try with `htmlentities()` on the server 1.